Plastic shed built on top of particle board floor which is rotting away
I have a plastic shed that is in really good shape, despite being probably 20 years old.  It was built on a raised wood frame which still seems to be level. But, the way it was constructed was: blocks, frame (4x6 pressure treated), particle board floor, THEN the shed built on top. The particle board is rotting away. I had planned to remove the rotten floor and lay a new plywood floor on the wood frame. But, the bits of particle board under the walls of the shed - it will still be resting on those if I do this.  Some of it (in visible areas, like the entrance) is crumbling. There are lots of things outside the shed, so many of which cannot be moved, and it's in a tight space. So I'm not sure jacking it up is an option, even if I could do that without breaking it.
I cannot tell how the shed is attached to the floor and I've searched for brand name but to no avail. A studfinder indicates some structure where the panels join, but I don't know how they join or if they attach to the floor. It's 10 x 20. I think there are 4x4 vertical wood posts in the 4 corners. I am not sure but I think the reason the floor has rotted out is not because of water leaking in (though that's a possibility), but because animals have gotten in and peed along the edges and in the corners. These are the rotten areas - not the center.
So, right now, I'm thinking that cutting the particle board just inside the walls and pulling it all out, laying plywood on the floor joists just to the inside edge of the walls, and using some sort of molding/cove base with silicone sealer to prevent water from seeping in, maybe applying epoxy to the particle board where I can get to it before laying the new floor?
I've seen a million posts and YouTube videos about how to replace sections of particle board floors that has gotten wet. And lots of them about rotting shed floors and rotting shed walls (wood).  How to jack up or move a plastic shed.  But none of these address the problem I have. I haven't seen anything about how to handle an intact plastic shed sitting on a rotted particleboard base.
There was one post here where someone did ask a similar question and one answer he got said to be sure to "block" the plywood. All the other advice was clear. One person asked what was meant by "blocking the plywood" but no answer was given. I repeated that question, but it was not allowed, as that is apparently not how this exchange is supposed to work. Thus this longer post/detailed question.
Thanks for your ideas.


** I have added two pictures to this post. One shows missing parts of the floor where it meets the walls. The other shows what I now realize is an aluminum channel that was attached to the particle board before the shed was assembled. This was shot from below, looking up.
Running my fingers along the underside of that channel, in the areas where the particle board is completely gone, the screws hanging down are loose and can be pushed up into the hollow channel.  The ones still embedded in the particle board feel secure. So, it seems like if I succeed in jacking it up, i will need to remove all particlboard residue and push all those screws up so they're not in the way of the new plywood base. But, how to attach shed to new base when it's now clear that it was attached from above - inside the channel before the walls were assembled?

Your description is very clear, but a picture is worth 1000 words so that could clarify even further. Can you take a couple pictures that show the areas you're talking about, and [edit] them into the post? There's a "mountains and sun" button to embed photos, or you can link them and we can embed for you.

Your question isn't very specific. Please take the [tour] and see if you can clarify what you're asking. My strategy would absolutely be to slide the shed off the base and rebuild it. If you decide to go your route, ok, but you need to ask something more pointed.

Pictures will help, but the shed should attached to the wood frame with screws/bolts.  Removing the screws/bolts should allow you to stuff 1/2 wood in to raise it up and remove what is under the edges.

I think the channel was screwed to the floor and then the walls screwed to the channel from the sides.  I think this will be hard to reverse it replicate.      I wouldn't want to remove the channel from the bottom of the walls.   You may need to see through those bottom screws to remove the floor and then to devise a new way to attach it back.  That should be a new question with those last two photos.

Your best bet is really to figure out how you can replace all of the floor including that under the bottom plate of the walls. The reason for this is because the support for the perimeter of the floor is the same as what supports the walls. Almost always if you cut around the inside of the walls the edges of the existing flooring become unsupported.
Blocking refers to adding some type of framing lumber pieces to the underlying floor framing structure to support the edges of flooring that would otherwise not be supported. Blocking can be pieces of framing lumber nailed or screwed between floor joists it the unsupported areas are perpendicular to the joists. In other cases blocking may be longer pieces of framing lumber nailed or screwed to the side of existing joists if the unsupported edges run parallel to the joists.
If you choose to just cut away the existing particle board up to the inside of the walls this is where you would be considering adding blocking. On the other hand if you were to jack up the building so you can replace the floor out under the bottom of the walls there would likely be no need to add blocking as the new floor would have all the same support as the original floor.

Thanks!  I knew I should not leave a small margin of crumbling particle board supporting the shed, and investing lots of effort and resources into fixing the rest of the floor.  But sometimes you need someone else to tell you that to make yourself do the extra work.  I appreciate your comments!

Partial answer here ... just to give you some direction, what I would do as a first step before deciding what to do next.
"Jacking up" a 10x20 plastic shed should be easy.  If you can release the shed from the floor, and just raise one corner at a time, you're lifting maybe 300 pounds, you can probably do it without a jack, just two guys or one guy with a lever.  Bear that in mind.

Remove a quarter of the floor, or half of it, to gain access to the joists.
Plan how you will lay out the new plywood in probably 8 to 12 pieces, where the edges will rest on joists.  And from that, the exact sizes of the four pieces that will rest under the four corners of the shed.
Figure out how the shed is attached to the floor. You have to do this.
Remove the attachments (screws or whatever) all around one corner of the shed.  Figure out a way to use a crow bar or a car jack or just a couple of guys to raise that corner about half an inch, and to keep it held up while you  cut/grind/smash out the floor from underneath it, and slide a new floor board in.
Repeat for other corners.  You'll have to release more of the shed from the floor when you jack it up, just do what you need to do.  You'll have to do the edge pieces too, not just the corners, while it's jacked up.

This is a rough outline and is not meant to be a detailed plan.  You'll be exploring, and adapting as you go.

Thank you.  I didn't think raising it up would be an option, but you've convinced me that I should at least try to figure out how to do it.  I do have a car jack (if you have a car you have one, right?) but I don't have a couple of guys.  Just me so it will take a lot of thought and planning.  This is exactly why I posted here.

Just to be pedantic and annoying ... not all cars have jacks any more.  So ya, that can be your first problem to solve. :)

Plastic, plus a missed anchor and a jack, is not a good day.

Could you please elaborate?  "a missed anchor and a jack".  I want to be prepared for problems and do whatever I can to avoid stupid mistakes.  I don't know what you mean by missed anchor but it seems like you are warning about something dangerous.

I think he means if you don't remove every screw holding down the shed, the jack will easily crush the bottom of the wall or rip the plastic off the screws.

Again ... you have to feel your way through this.  If the walls have "studs" or any rib-like structure to them where some parts are stronger than others, probably in the corners, you could drill a small hole through a solid part, insert a metal rod, and use that as your jacking point.  Makes it easier to do the floor, anyway, if your jack isn't holding the bottom of the wall.

You want to be VERY sure to not use a scissor type car jack. These are very unsturdy if using them to just push up on a long or loose member. They work well on your car because generally the top of the jack notches into the frame or structure seam of the car body.

The best bet for jacking is to make an triangular frame and put a small hydraulic jack on top and jack up on the upper part of your structure. Much less chance of some dangerous situation occurring due to misunderstood rigging.

I wish I knew the make or model or whatever of this shed.  I was under the impression that what holds these together is the roof, so if that's the case, jacking that up would probably be a bad idea, no?  I won't do anything till I know more.  And each one of these answers teaches me something so more thanks.

All this jack advice ... it's one corner of a 1000lb plastic shed.  Put a bolt through the corner  as I suggested, cut a 2x4 just long enough to reach the floor, cut a small notch in one end for the bolt, and lift the other end with a wrecking bar.   .....

.... Or if you want to feel less hacky use one of those fridge lifters with the little blocks.  Or two of them.   My fridge weighs about 375lbs and I used one of those to lift it on to wheels by myself with one arm lifting totally effortlessly and the other manipulating the wheels.
